# You cannot access the resource from this browser on your device. you need to use safari or edge

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, multi-factor-authentication

In my Xamarin Application, AD login is not working in iOS simulator getting this error "you cannot access the resource from this browser on your device. you need to use safari or edge", error code is 530001.But the login is working in UWP and android and also it was working on iOS earlier. Please help on this am stuck on this.

Comment: Have you contacted your AD admin?  There are a number of hits on that error that point to an AD policy that restricts uses to certain browsers

Comment: Okay, I will check with the AD admin

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem on our side?Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem so that we can try to test on our side?

Comment: @Swathy have you solved this issue? currently, I am having exactly the same problem

Comment: @RaGibNoor Yes, I connected with azure team they share new credentials for this